barba.js: dynamic transition adding
I use barba.js for page transitions on my wordpress website. Everything runs fine.
I'm developing currently a plugin which uses the template_include filter. I'd like to add seperate   transition effects only for these pages without touching the barba init function from the main script file in the current theme.
I tried using the barba.transitions.store.add function in the plugin js-script file, but getting the error
barba.js?ver=2.9.7:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'priority')" 

in the console.
My code so far:
function addNewTransition() {
    barba.transitions.store.add({
        name: 'fade',
        leave() {},
        beforeLeave() {
            jQuery('.transition_title').removeClass('transition_logo');
        },
        enter() {},
        to: {
            namespace: ['custom-page']
        }
    });
}

function waitForBarbaInitialization(callback) {
    if (typeof barba !== 'undefined' && barba.transitions && barba.transitions.store) {
        callback();
    } else {
        setTimeout(() => waitForBarbaInitialization(callback), 100);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    waitForBarbaInitialization(addNewTransition);
});

Can someone tell me what I'm missing?
Thanks in advance.
